# Equivalence of from dual in PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I work with Hibernate and Oracle. I used this code :

```
     if (null != sessionFactory) {
                Session s = currentSession.get();
    
                if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    currentSession.set(s);
                } else {
                    try {
                        HibernateWork hibernateWork = new HibernateWork("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
                        s.doWork(hibernateWork);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       
                        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                        currentSession.set(s);
                    }
                }
    
                return s;
            }
```

I want to do the same thing with PostgreSQL, but PostgreSQL does NOT support the ‘FROM dual’ syntax. I want to know equivalence of  **dual** in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You don't need a `FROM` clause at all. Just `SELECT 1` will do it.

Comment: what if I needed multiple rows for one column?

Comment: @Luna You can `select n from generate_series(1,5) s(n)`

Answer (score 18):

PostgreSQL has implicit DUAL table, just write:

```
SELECT NOW  ()

Output:    
2019-05-17 13:56:51.120277+02
```

In case that you Oracle PL/SQL code is referring DUAL
table you can create own DUAL table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.public.dual (column1 bool);
```

Answer (score 17):

Just use `select 1`. From [documentation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion)

> Oracle uses the "fake" dual table for many selects, where in PostgreSQL we can write *select* just without *from* part at all. This table was created in postgres as a view to ease porting problems. This allows code to remain somewhat compatible with Oracle SQL without annoying the Postgres parser.

Comment: DUAL is not a fake table, it's as real as any other table. Try inserting a row into DUAL. But have your entire database backup ready! (At least in older versions of Oracle).

Answer (score 5):

don't forget  to  insert a  row in your "dual" table, thus in order  for  the "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" to work!

Answer (score 4):

Just create one, if you really want to:

```
CREATE TABLE dual();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in Postgres would be to use the [VALUES command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) to create a single-element array and use it in the FROM clause, such as:

```sql
SELECT 'foo' FROM (VALUES(1)) i;
```

This may prove useful if you want or need to express a SELECT statement with a FROM clause, for clarity purposes or when nested in a function or command that may require it.

---

If you absolutely *must* call `dual` (for script portability reasons, or otherwise) the workaround I found was the most efficient, direct, and closest to the Oracle behavior is to use a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dual AS
    SELECT 'X' as DUMMY from (VALUES('X')) i;
```

In this case, the view approach seems more appropriate to me given the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Selecting-from-the-DUAL-Table.html) stating:

> *Beginning with Oracle Database 10g Release 1, logical I/O is not performed on the DUAL table when computing an expression that does not include the DUMMY column [...]*

Output:

```
postgres=# CREATE VIEW dual AS
    SELECT 'X' as DUMMY from (VALUES('X')) i;
CREATE VIEW
postgres=# select * from dual;
 dummy
-------
 X
(1 row)

postgres=# select 1 from dual;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```