# How to find next row in ordered table that matches a condition, given an initial match in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm querying a table that contains state transitions for a state engine. The table is set up so that it has the `previous_state`, `current_state`, and `timestamp` of the transition, grouped by unique `id`s.

My goal is to find a sequence of target intervals, defined as timestamp of the initial state transition (eg timestamp when we shift from from 1->2), and timestamp of the target next state transition that matches a specific condition (eg the next timestamp that current_state=3 OR current_state=4).

```
state_transition_table
+------------+---------------+-----------+----+
| prev_state | current_state | timestamp | id |
+------------+---------------+-----------+----+
|          1 |             2 |       4.5 |  1 |
|          2 |             3 |       5.2 |  1 |
|          3 |             1 |       5.4 |  1 |
|          1 |             2 |      10.3 |  1 |
|          2 |             5 |      10.4 |  1 |
|          5 |             4 |      10.8 |  1 |
|          4 |             1 |      11.0 |  1 |
|          1 |             2 |      12.3 |  1 |
|          2 |             3 |      13.5 |  1 |
|          3 |             1 |      13.6 |  1 |
+------------+---------------+-----------+----+
```

Within a given id, we want to find all intervals that start with 1->2 (easy enough query), and end with either state 3 or 4.
1->2->*anything*->3 or 4

An example output table given the input above would have the three states and the timestamps for when we transition between the states:

```
target output
+------------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| prev_state | current_state | end_state  | curr_time | end_time  |
+------------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|          1 |             2 |          3 |       4.5 |       5.2 |
|          1 |             2 |          4 |      10.3 |      10.8 |
|          1 |             2 |          3 |      12.3 |      13.5 |
+------------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

The best query I could come up with is using window functions in a sub-table, and then creating the new columns from that table. But this solution *only* finds the next row following the initial transition, and doesnt allow other states to occur between then and when our target state arrives.

```sql
WITH state_transitions as (
SELECT
  id
  previous_state, current_state,
  LEAD(current_state) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) AS end_state,
  timestamp as curr_time,
  LEAD(timestamp) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) AS end_time
FROM
  state_transition_table

SELECT
  previous_state,
  current_state,
  end_state,
  curr_time,
  end_time
FROM state_transitions
WHERE previous_state=1 and current_state=2
ORDER BY curr_time
```

This query would incorrectly give the second output row `end_state==5`, which is not what I am looking for.

How can one search a table for the next row that matches my target condition, eg `end_state=3 OR end_state=4`?

Comment: What is a "target interval"?  Those two terms are not used in the definition of your data.  I find the explanation hard to follow.

Comment: I clarify what a target interval is in the first paragraph, as the pair of timestamps where the first timestamp is an initial state transition (eg 1->2), and the second timestamp is the next timestamp after the initial state that the state changes to states 3 or 4. 
Editing to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a recursive query that checks each row against siblings. This query should account for more than three rows. I assumed ORACLE for the seed data, may need to adapt your syntax to your database engine. I tried to document the query as best as I thought it was needed.

```
WITH /*SEED DATA*/
  state_transition_table(prev_state, current_state, time_stamp, id) as (
              SELECT          1 ,             2 ,       4.5 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          2 ,             3 ,       5.2 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          3 ,             1 ,       5.4 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          1 ,             2 ,      10.3 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          2 ,             5 ,      10.4 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          5 ,             4 ,      10.8 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          4 ,             1 ,      11.0 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          1 ,             2 ,      12.3 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          2 ,             3 ,      13.5 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT          3 ,             1 ,      13.6 ,  1 --FROM DUAL
)

/*THE END STATES YOU ARE LOOKING FOR*/
, end_states (a_state) as (
              select 3 --FROM DUAL
    union all select 4 --FROM DUAL
)

/*ORDER THE STEPS TO USE THE order_id COLUMN TO EVALUATE THE NEXT NODE*/
, ordered_states as (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp)  order_id
         , prev_state
         , current_state
         , id
         , time_stamp
    FROM   state_transition_table
)

/*RECURSIVE QUERY WITH ANSI SYNTAX*/
, recursive (
           root_order_id
         , order_id
         , time_stamp
         , prev_state
         , current_state
         --, id

         , steps
  )
as (
    SELECT order_id root_order_id /*THE order_id OF EACH ROOT ROW*/
         , order_id
         , time_stamp
         , prev_state
         , current_state

         , CAST(order_id as char(100)) as steps /*INITIAL VALIDATION PATH*/
    FROM   ordered_states
    WHERE  prev_state = 1 AND current_state = 2 /*INITIAL CONDITION*/

    UNION ALL
    SELECT prev.root_order_id
         , this.order_id
         , this.time_stamp
         , prev.prev_state
         , this.current_state

         , CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(prev.steps)), ', '), RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(this.order_id as char(3))))) as char(100)) as steps
    FROM   recursive prev /*ANSI PSEUDO TABLE*/
         , ordered_states this /*THE SIBLING ROW TO CHECK*/

    WHERE prev.order_id = this.order_id - 1 /*ROW TO PREVIOUS ROW JOIN*/
      and prev.current_state not in (select a_state from end_states) /*THE PREVIOUS ROW STATE IS NOT AN END STATE */
)

select init_state.prev_state
     , init_state.current_state as mid_state /*this name is better, I think*/
     , end_state.current_state
     , init_state.time_stamp as initial_time /*initial_time is better, I think*/
     , end_state.time_stamp as end_time /*end_time is better, I think*/
     , recursive.steps as validation_path_by_order_id
from   recursive
inner join ordered_states init_state
    on init_state.order_id = recursive.root_order_id
inner join ordered_states end_state
    on end_state.order_id = recursive.order_id
where  recursive.current_state in (select a_state from end_states)
```

One final note. The resulting columns are only accounting for 3 rows (prev_state, mid_state and current_state). As I said above, there are cases where you can have a path from (1) to (2) to (3 or 4) with more than three rows, lets say 1 to 2 to 5 to 2 to 3, thus the mid_state is really just one state in the middle.

Final-final note: Your desired results table was wrong, but you corrected it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I didn't know that recursive queries could be done in SQL.

Updated the output table with correct outputs; I had shifted the input table to be more clear in what the states were, and didnt update the output table.

Comment: I've been trying to run it on my postgres table, but finding that the Oracle-isms don't work, such as the 'dual' temporary table for `end_states`, or `rownum` as the `order_id`. I'm not sure how to replicate this solution in SQL, as it seems like the `order_id` is what the recursion is iterating over.

Comment: Oracle's dual is not needed in Postgres. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303638/equivalence-of-from-dual-in-postgresql#30303679. Rownum is different too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959692/rownum-in-postgresql#3959748