# INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS query that works for both Postgres and Oracle

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I need to create an `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` SQL query that works on both Postgres and Oracle. Unfortunately, since oracle does not support `SELECT` statements without `FROM` I'm struggling to get this query to work.

I found this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639922 ) and implemented my query very similarly:

```
insert into TABLE (col1, col2) 
select 'A', 100
from dual
where not exists(select * 
                 from TABLE 
                 where (col1='A' and col2=100));
```

The one part that causes me issues here is the `from dual` statement. In postgres I would just omit this part and the query works. But for oracle it is necessary to add a `FROM` statement so I have to select from some table. Unfortunately postgres does not have a `DUAL` table. Is there any dummy table that I can select from in both cases, or is there an entirely different way to write that query? My initial approach with postgres' `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` obviously also wasn't viable for oracle.

Comment: Add your own `dual` to postgres for extra compatibility? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77616867/21105992

Answer (score 1):

SELECT from a VALUES clause derived table to mimic the DUAL table.

```
insert into TABLE (col1, col2) 
select 'A', 100
from (values(1)) dt(c1)
where not exists(select * 
                 from TABLE 
                 where (col1='A' and col2=100));
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/oyCVXg5a

The following features outside ISO/ANSI Core SQL-2023 are used:
F591, Derived tables
F661, Simple tables

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view in PostgreSQL to mimic the `DUAL` table:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dual(dummy) AS
  SELECT dummy FROM (VALUES('X')) AS dual(dummy);
```

Then, in both Oracle and PostgreSQL, you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) 
SELECT 'A', 100
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table_name
         WHERE  col1='A'
         AND    col2=100
       );
```

or, probably more efficiently:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT 'A' AS col1, 100 AS col2 FROM DUAL
) src
ON (src.col1 = dst.col1 AND src.col2 = dst.col2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (col1, col2)
  VALUES (src.col1, src.col2);
```

*Note: From Oracle 23, the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement is optional and you can just use `SELECT 'A' AS col1, 100 AS col2` and could use identical queries in PostgreSQL and Oracle without the need for a `DUAL` table.*

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H2afA8ms) [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BWP6xT3p)

Answer (score 0):

On Postgres you don't need any actual table or `FROM` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) 
SELECT 'A', 100
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT      -- we don't even need to select anything here
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE col1 = 'A' AND col2 = 100
);
```

Note that in Postgres, we also don't even need to select anything in the exists clause.

A general version which should work on both Oracle and Postgres might just put the data into a CTE and then select from that.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS col1, 100 AS col2
)

INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2
FROM cte
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE col1 = 'A' AND col2 = 100
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that. I need to come up with one single query that works on BOTH postgres AND oracle.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue either, since the first select statement is again missing a FROM clause.